# Compairing player-stage and ros-stage for multiple robots?

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on stage simulator in ROS with multiple robots. I have written a code to move robot in stage simulator. When I try to run that code on 2 or 3 robots in stage, every robot has some different speed. Robot that starts moving first have high speed.

In player-stage we run .cfg file using player. Separate ports are assigned in .cfg file in case of multiple robots. i.e.

```
driver
(
name "stage"
provides ["6665:position2d:0"
"6665:sonar:0"
"6665:blobfinder:0"
"6665:laser:0"]
model "bob1"
)
```

But I am confused that how multiple robots are separated in stage-simulator in ros?

Can I run each robot on separate port in ROS?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38813/compairing-player-stage-and-ros-stage-for-multiple-robots?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-15**:
You probably need to collect more information for anyone to answer a question like this.

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2012-07-20**:
@Arkapravo Thanks a lot. I was very much confused. Have you run navigation-stage tutorial? When we use move_base with multiple robots, robots have same speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@abdullah I am not sure about fuerte, but electric and diamondback did not have such a support for multi-robot simulations. http://answers.ros.org/question/11192/swarm-robotics-facility-in-ros/

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1